# Change month from jan to Jan. in reference

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I am using Mendeley to manage my references. Mendeley generates `library.bib`, I am using when I write a paper.

The `library.bib` file is generated by Mendeley, it looks like

```
Automatically generated by Mendeley Desktop 1.17.11
Any changes to this file will be lost if it is regenerated by Mendeley.
BibTeX export options can be customized via Options -> BibTeX in Mendeley Desktop
@article{citationkey,
abstract = {...},
author = {...},
doi = {...},
file = {:path.pdf:pdf},
isbn = {-},
issn = {-},
journal = {-},
keywords = {a,b,c},
mendeley-tags = {a,b,c},
month = {apr},
number = {4},
pages = {100--105},
pmid = {0000},
title = {{TITLE}},
url = {http://abc.com},
volume = {100},
year = {2016}
}

@inproceedings{citation2,
...
```

, even I change this manually, it is returned based on the entries in Mendeley.

If I open the `library.bib` by JabRef, then I can see this `month = {nov},` item from every entry.

The problem is when I import the references in my `mytex.tex` using

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{library}
```

, it shows

```
[1] Author, “Title,” Journal, jun 2017.
```

But what I want to do is

```
[1] Author, “Title,” Journal, Jun. 2017.
```

You can see `.bst` what I am using from here: [ctan.org](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex?lang=en).

I tried to change this `IEEEtran.bst` file, I only could find the code below

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% PREDEFINED STRING MACROS %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

MACRO {jan} {"Jan."}
MACRO {feb} {"Feb."}
MACRO {mar} {"Mar."}
MACRO {apr} {"Apr."}
MACRO {may} {"May"}
MACRO {jun} {"Jun."}
MACRO {jul} {"Jul."}
MACRO {aug} {"Aug."}
MACRO {sep} {"Sep."}
MACRO {oct} {"Oct."}
MACRO {nov} {"Nov."}
MACRO {dec} {"Dec."}
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to use these macros.

Even there seems to be related to publication date item in `IEEEtran.bst`, but still I could not find the way to use the above macros.

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{
  month "month" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
  year  "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    { swap$ 'skip$
        { this.to.prev.status
          this.status.std
          cap.status.std
         "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$ }
      if$
      *
    }
    { this.to.prev.status
      this.status.std
      cap.status.std
      swap$ 'skip$
        {
          swap$
          " " * swap$
        }
      if$
      *
    }
  if$
}
```

.

And I would like to know how to edit or modify `.bst`, but I could not find any manual yet.

If someone knows it, please let me know.

Comment: Can you please show a minimal compilable document that shows the code you use to generate the bibliography, along with a sample `.bib` file item that shows the problem.  Because the conversion should be done automatically.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you for your interest. Here is the link, I will update the question. Here is the link, https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex?lang=en

Comment: That's not what I asked for. The link isn't helpful. See [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/2693).

Comment: @AlanMunn I will revise it now :) thank you!

Comment: Look at @mico 's answer and then your question. The `.bib` entry is helpful, but you also need to show the document code that produces the problem. (And the rest of your question is really not necessary.)  The point is a bit moot now, since you have a correct answer, but for future questions you should really post minimal compilable documents that show the problem you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the curly braces from the argument of the `month` field. E.g., instead of

```
month = {nov},
```

you need

```
month = nov,
```

to achieve your objective.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{aa,
  author = "Anne Author",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year   = 3001,
  month  = jan,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But it is not what I write, it is generated by Mendeley. And I cannot revise it manually unless I don't use Mendeley.

Comment: @Creatlee - Can't you edit the Mendeley database?

Comment: This is a problem with Mendeley, not TeX.  And it has further ramifications too. See https://mendeley.uservoice.com/forums/4941-general/suggestions/469422-add-an-option-to-disable-double-curly-brackets-aro

Comment: @AlanMunn, Mico I really appreciate to you for the answer! The link, Alan you shared here, is what I looked for! I didnt know about these known errors in Mendeley. I definitely have a look, and do it . And about my MWEB,, I really have almost nothing particular lines in .tex file. But I really appreciate to you! Have a good day!

Comment: @Creatlee -You're most welcome! I suspect that until and unless Mendeley fixes what should be considered to be a bug, *viz*., its insistence on automatically surrounding the contents of a field with curly braces, you may be stuck with having to write `month = `{Jan.}`, etc. A better bet may be to export the Mendeley database to a .bib file and to strip off the surplus curly braces from the `month` fields. (Of course, do this only once the list of bib entries is more or less final.)